# Unexpected expression after operator in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I am relatively new to Swift and Playground. When experimenting in playground, I wrote a piece of Swift code to calculate the averages of 5 numbers

```
func avg (scores: [Int]) -> (Int){
    var avg = 0
    var total = 0
    var count = 0

    for score in scores {
        total += score
        count ++
    }   // Error: unexpected expression after operator

    avg = total/count

    return avg
}

let score = avg([10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
print(score)
```

However, it keeps giving me this error "unexpected expression after operator" (see above in comments in the code). Can someone please explain why.

Comment: Pah for loops... embrace functional programming ;) `scores.reduce(0, combine: +) / scores.count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading.

The actual error reason is the space character between `count` and `++`.
The postfix operator must follow the operand directly without any whitespace.

Anyhow you should always use the forward compatible syntax

```
count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for score in scores {
    total += score
    count ++
}   // Error: unexpected expression after operator
```

The ++ shortcut will be removed in Swift 3. You need to do this

```
for score in scores {
    total += score
    count = count + 1
}
```

else you can't have a space between count and ++

so

```
count++
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
func average(scores: [Int]) -> Int {
    var avg = 0
    for number in numbers {
        avg += score
    }
    var  ave  = (avg)/(scores.count)
    return ave
}
```

And you're just dividing the `total` with the `count` which you've declared as 0. You need the count of the array `[Int]`. So you need to do `scores.count` which gives u the number of elements in that array.